# Who was the first to propose a formal definition of infinity?

Tags: set-theory, ho.history-overview

In a recent [Quanta article](https://www.quantamagazine.org/ninth-dedekind-number-found-by-two-independent-groups-20230801/) about the 9th Dedekind number, Dedekind is credited with the first formal definition of infinity.

> Is this an accurate attribution?

Folklore where I’m from dictates that Georg Cantor is the father of modern infinity, but they were alive and working concurrently and I’m not familiar enough with either mathematician’s body of work to pin down when he first proposed a formal definition of infinity. Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: What makes a definition "formal"?

Comment: The answer could also be different depending on whether one asks for the first definition of "infinite" as an adjective, "infinity" or "infinite" as a noun, or "infinite set." Do you want answers to all these questions or only one of them, and if only one of them, which one? The SEP [article on infinity](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/infinity/) should be a good starting point in any case.

Comment: @TimothyChow Working in some formal language with some axioms would qualify as ‘formal’ to me; I was hoping that the best interpretation would be sussed out through discussion. (I find the SEP verbose and tedious to read personally, but I’ll take a look)

Comment: WHICH definition of infinity you have in mind? This term is used in mathematics in many different senses.

Comment: Formal languages are a relatively late development. Even Russell and Whitehead's *Principia Mathematica* was not fully formal by modern standards, as Gödel pointed out. Frege's system was famously vulnerable to Russell's paradox, so maybe that doesn't count either. In any case, formal definitions of infinity in this sense came later than either Dedekind or Cantor, and therefore shifts the emphasis of your question from the word "infinity" to the word "formal". By the way, *most* definitions in mathematics have never been formally stated in this sense.

Comment: @TimothyChow That is interesting, but why I specifically phrased my comment as ‘would qualify as’ and not ‘is the only definition of’; I would be curious to see how the standards of rigor have evolved, and am open to considering whatever Dedekind and Cantor were working with to be ‘formal’.

Comment: Would anyone voting to close care to explain the sense in which this isn’t about mathematics?

Comment: This question definitely belongs on https://hsm.stackexchange.com/ instead of here.

Comment: @SamHopkins I literally remembered that hsm existed and visited there just now, whence I saw the notification for your comment here lol. I agree, but can't delete and repost the question there because it has a positively received answer here now. Is there a standard remedy in cases like this?

Comment: The Greek mathematics avoided to speak about infinity, yet Euclid's statement of the theorem of infinitude of primes implicitly contains a definition, "Prime numbers are more than any given (finite) group of them"

Comment: @PietroMajer That the notion of “potential” vs “actual” infinity has not been mentioned yet is strange. And indeed the “potential” line of thought is what the Greeks thought of infinity (lines are not “actual” infinitely long, but they can be extended indefinitely to any finite length; and so too can any finite list of primes).

Comment: @PietroMajer, being able to find more than any given finite number is not the same as having an infinite set.  For example, you can work in Peano Arithmetic and never come across an infinite collection, and in fact PA is equiconsistent with the usual axiomatisation of set theory with the axiom of infinity replaced by its negation.

Comment: @MikhailKatz A potentially infinite set (like the example given by PietroMajer) is “not the same as an infinite set” only if you take a certain definition of infinite set as given…

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda Given the discussion and the clarifying comments by the OP, I think a somewhat more accurate phrasing of the intended question would be, "Who was the first to give an explicit mathematical definition of an '[actually] infinite set'?"

Comment: @AlecRhea Your question is interesting in some respects but MO is only for contemporary research-level questions.

Comment: @HollisWilliams, the existence of the math-history tag indicates that MO is not only for contemporary research-level questions, or at least "contemporary research-level questions" should be interpreted broadly to include whatever the professional mathematicians at MO are interested in.  I think it would be reasonable to vote to re-open the question.

Comment: @MikhailKatz I think it would be fine to re-open the question if it were made slightly more precise, it seems quite vague at the moment and open to the interpretation of the reader what the OP is referring to.

Comment: @Hollis, Why do you think the current wording is ambiguous?  Most users here interpret it as referring to the definition of an infinite set as it was developed by Cantor and Dedekind.  It is true that there is at least one user who thought this refers to a more general notion of infinity, but I think he is in a minority.  At any rate, the problem can be solved by adding a "set-theory" tag.

Comment: @MikhailKatz I agree with Hollis Williams that the wording isn't very clear. For a start, the cited Quanta article uses the word "rigorous" rather than "formal," which is not the same thing. On the other hand, the subsequent discussion in these comments has more or less clarified the intended question.

Comment: @TimothyChow, in my opinion "formal" is an improvement on "rigorous" which is a rather vague term if you think about it.  "Formal" is more specific and has a definite meaning.  Clearly, Quanta is using "rigorous" in the sense of "formal".

Comment: @MikhailKatz Well, I have to say that I'm not clear on what this alleged "definite meaning" of "formal" is (that was my first question). But again, I agree that the intended question is now pretty clear.

Comment: @TimothyChow, I didn't notice your first question.  A "formal definition" is a definition given in a specific logical system, such as the ZF axiomatisation.  Why is that unclear?  Unlike "formal", the term "rigorous" has multiple meanings which have evolved over time.  Dedekind of course was before ZF, but the question would be what was the first definition that could easily be formalized in traditional frameworks we use today.

Comment: @MikhailKatz So you're saying that when Quanta used "rigorous" they meant *formalizable* rather than *formal*, right? Maybe. None of this is as clear to me as it seems to be to you.

Comment: @TimothyChow: that's how I understood Alec's question.  Now that you mention it, I see that it would have been preferable to use "formalizable" instead of "formal".

Comment: To be transparent, when Timothy pointed out that I had used a different word than the quanta article I did a disbelieving double-take -- when I asked the question I tried to use the specific phrasing from the article, so thank you for pointing out my error. (Not to be overly formal ;^)

Comment: By the way, FWIW, my experience is that when a research paper talks about giving a "formal definition," it usually means an *explicit* and *unambiguous* definition, which will serve as the *official* definition if anyone has doubts about what exactly is meant. A "formal" definition in this sense will generally be "rigorous" and "formalizable in a formal language," but most mathematicians take "rigor" for granted and are also *not* thinking about formal languages. What "formal" means is that they will formally write "Definition" and will give enough details to clarify any ambiguities.

Answer (score 22):

Dedekind actually in effect gave two different definitions of infinity.

Namely, first, as is well known, a set is *Dedekind infinite* if it is equinumerous with a proper subset of itself.

But second, Dedekind proved the famous categoricity result for the natural numbers, showing that the natural-number structure of the successor operation $\langle\mathbb{N},0,S\rangle$ is characterized up to isomorphism by the properties (1) zero is not a sucessor; (2) the successor operation is one-to-one; and (3) every number is generated from zero by successor, in the sense that if $X$ is a set with $0\in X$ and $n\in X\implies Sn\in X$, then every number is in $X$. This (second-order) theory is now known as Dedekind arithmetic, and Dedekind showed how to undertake definition by recursion and thereby to develop all the usual number theory and arithmetic in this structure. Peano famously provided a hugely successful and quite elegant development of the theory on the basis of Dedekind's axioms, and these days the theory is often attributed to Peano, even though Peano credits Dedekind.

The point is that the categoricity result defines what it means to be finite — a set is *(numerically) finite* if it is equinumerous with the predecessors of a natural number. A set is infinite, accordingly, if it is not finite.

It seems to me that Dedekind probably believed that his two definitions were equivalent, and indeed they are provably equivalent in ZFC. Nevertheless, we now know that this requires the axiom of choice (countable choice suffices), and it is consistent with ZF that there are numerically infinite sets that are Dedekind finite. It is the second definition (numerically infinite) that is usually taken as the right choice in contemporary mathematics.

Finally, let me mention my essay, [Equinumerosity and the definition of finiteness](https://www.infinitelymore.xyz/p/equinumerosity-and-the-definition), in which I discuss Aristotle, Galileo, Frege, Dedekind, Cantor, Tarski and others on the meaning of finiteness. Further discussion in my essay [Potential versus actual infinity](https://www.infinitelymore.xyz/p/potential-versus-actual-infinity), which is freely available, and which brings in Archimedes, as well as ultrafinitism and the contemporary modal analysis of potentialism.

Comment: Very cool as always Joel, thank you; I agree with the assertion that any putative definition $\varphi$ of what 'finite' means implicitly offers a definition $\neg\varphi$ of 'infinite', and in this sense all the people mentioned in your essay have been implicitly considering what 'infinity' means via negation. This connection between the finite and infinite is obvious once pointed out, and a prime example of why I love MO!

Comment: One nitpick: the equivalence of not-finite and Dedekind-infinite doesn't require the whole axiom of choice, but a fragment of countable choice... see eg https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3985461/strength-of-cofinite-choice/3985520#3985520   (otherwise, nice to see you here again, Joel).

Comment: @DavidRoberts Yes, countable choice suffices. (And thanks for the welcome!)

Comment: An important detail: the notion we now call "Dedekind infinite" was proposed by Dedekind as an example of a *bad (but correct)* definition of infinity. Dedekind himself very much preferred the "numerically infinite" definition.

Comment: I think it is one of the magical, and yet disturbing, aspects of mathematics that the natural definition of finite requires us to implicitly understand what "all the subsets of N" means.

Comment: @PaceNielsen Yes, in my view the situation is unsatisfactory and I have argued that we should perhaps be much less sure than people often are that we have isolated a singular notion of finiteness. After all, how can it be sensible to base our confidence in a definite concept of the finite on the comparatively murky concept of "arbitrary set of numbers"? I find ample room for a philosophy of arithmetic pluralism, which would explain a lot of the phenomenon we have discovered in the foundations of mathematics. See my brief essay at https://jdh.hamkins.org/question-for-the-math-oracle/.

Answer (score 16):

The article is probably referring to Dedekind's *Was sind und was sollen die Zahlen* of 1888, in which point 64 is Dedekind's definition of infinite. This of course is after Cantor had been investigating various infinities for several years, though I'm not sure where Cantor made a formal definition.

Comment: Thank you, I realized while reading your post that I’m not familiar enough with Cantor’s work to say when he first wrote down what might amount to a formal definition either; I’ll edit the question accordingly.

Comment: @AlecRhea : The preface of that Dedekind monograph actually cites Cantor’s 1878 *Beitrag zur Mannigfaltigkeitslehre*, which I *think* is the first appearance of the concept of different set “cardinalities” as defined via bijection. But I don’t recall it containing a formal definition of infinity per se.

Answer (score 14):

The idea that infinite sets, if they existed, would admit 1-1 correspondences with their proper parts was well understood already in the 17th century, and were the reason such sets were rejected as contradictory.  Dedekind's insight was to turn a contradiction into a definition.  Cantor's work certainly prepared the ground for Dedekind turning the tables on the old contradiction.

Comment: Very interesting, any chance you can pin down dates precisely for Cantor (or point in a direction where I might be able to)?

Answer (score 6):

In the preface of the second edition of *Was sind und was sollen die Zahlen* Dedekind mentions another definition of `finite': a set $S$ is called finite if there is a map $\varphi$ from $S$ to itself such that $S$ itself is the only non-empty set that is closed under $\varphi$.

He investigated this definition in [Zweite definition (1889. 3. 9) des Endlichen und Unendlichen](https://edu.nl/wbqx4). In a note at the end Emmy Noether shows that this notion corresponds to what Joel calls (numerically) finite and that $\varphi$ is a cyclic permutation of $S$.

Answer (score 3):

Aristotle gave two definitions - possibly three - and probably not 'formally' as you would like it. Nevertheless, they have definitions.

The infinite is described as something without end, ie it is not finite which is what the word itself implies and presumably where the word can be traced back to. And he distinguished two different cases - the potential infinite and the actual infinite. I suspect it is the latter that fed into Cantor's semi-mystical notion of the absolute infinite.

He also distinguished this from the All - of which I would write more if I could remember what he wrote. But it's been sometime since I read his Physics/Metaphysics.

Comment: Mozibur, there is certainly a variety of opinions in the mathematical community with regard to the notion of an infinite set, with some that consider it semi-mystical and others who take it for granted as part of a traditional formalisation of the foundations of mathematics.  But Alec Rhea's question concerns the notion of an infinite set as it was developed by Cantor and Dedekind, which is an issue separate from the question whether such a notion is mystical or otherwise.

Comment: @MikhailKatz: Well this is what he says on the body of the question but I was more interested in the headline question where he asks who was "the first to propose a formal definition of infinity". Also, I'd argue that Cantorian infinites are examples of potential infinities and not actual infinites.

Comment: You wrote: "Cantorian infinites are examples of potential infinities and not actual infinites": I don't have the impression many people at this site would know what you mean by this.  I would certainly be interested in hearing some details.

Comment: A potential infinite cannot be complete but an actual infinite is complete in itself. It's infinite but at the same time there is no successor to it.  Ordinals and cardinals are ordered hence there's always a successor. Thus they're examples of potential infinites. There is no example of an actual infinite. Thats why I said it was a semi-mystical concept for Cantor.

Comment: You seem to be changing the meaning of the terms.  This is fine so long as you acknowledge it, but without explanation it doesn't make a good impression.  Let's take a simple example.  The set $\mathbb N$ of natural numbers is generally considered to be an actually infinite set.  Its mathematical existence doesn't follow from general philosophical principles, but rather from the axiom of infinity of Zermelo-Fraenkel set theory.  Certainly one can include it in a larger set, but this is generally not considered a reason to refrain from calling it an actually infinite set...

Comment: ... Why would one apply the term "actual infinite" to refer to something that does not exist, as you write?    Of course, Aristotle and Leibniz (and many authors in between) would have rejected the notion of $\mathbb N$ is contradictory.  But that's not a reason to change standard terminology.

Comment: @Mikail Katz: Because there are other ways to think about it. To quote Shakespeare's Hamlet, "there are more things in Heaven and Earth than are dreamt of in your philosophy". After all, it inspired Cantor to think about the absolute infinite. One might posit that the actual infinite is an attribute of Spinoza's One which os simply not directly cognisable by us mere finite and mortal humans. Aristotle would have described N as a potential infinity. He would have declined to say N was a complete infinity. And he's right, because right after N is N+1, and after that N+2, all the way upto 2N ...

Comment: @Mikail Katz: ... and then after that, 2N +1, 2N+2 etc. I'm sure you know how that game plays out. Tell me, why stop at N?

Comment: This discussion seems to me to be about terminology, rather. With my understanding of the common meaning of the word "actual",  an actually infinite set can be a proper subset of another actually infinite set. To me, an example of a potentially infinite "set" would be the sequence $(\{1,\dots,n\}\colon n=1,2,\dots)$ -- "a variable finite set growing to infinity".

Comment: @Losif Pinelus: No, it is not about terminology. You're mistaken. A complete or actual infinity is one that cannot have a successor in any sense. If you think I'm mistaken, then please explain why Cantor thought it important to think up the notion of an absolute infinity - which is all but an actual or complete infinity in all but name.

Comment: @losif Pinelis: The reason why that isn't taught in mathematical concept is because it resists mathematisation, for obvious reasons, as Cantor realised. Thus mathematicians ignore and trip over it when they come across it. It's a mathematico-philosophical construct.

Comment: @Mikhail Katz: The axiom of infinity in ZFC is only the first axiom of infinity. There is a whole sequence of ever larger 'infinities', but none of them are complete infinities in Aristotle's term, simply because there is a succesor. I don't see why this obvious point is so hard to see. Instead of looking clearly you are retreating into formalism. I am not "changing the meaning of terms" as you put but simply using Aristotle terms in ways that are novel to you but obviously are strongly motivated by his philosophy. After all, would Newton recog ise Newtonian mechanics today? Of course not.

Comment: @Mikhail Katz: But it is obviously rooted in his mechanics once one studies the relationships of these ideas in historical terms.

Comment: Why would Newton not recognize Newtonian mechanics today?

Comment: @Hollis Williams: Vector calculus, rigid body dynamics, Lagrangian method, Hamiltonian method, canonical transformations are all part of classical mechanics today but not part of what was dreamt up by Newton.

Comment: @MoziburUllah Oh right, I see what you mean now.

Comment: @MoziburUllah wrote "Tell me, why stop at N?"  Well, $\mathbb N$ is the smallest inductive set.  One can certainly go beyond it.  But it remains true that $\mathbb N$ is an actual infinity, according to the traditional meaning of the term.

Comment: "Aristotle would have described N as a potential infinity": I don't think this is accurate.  To Aristotle, potential infinity meant that any finite segment can be increased by doubling, and again doubled, and again doubled, ...  One can't reach $\mathbb N$ that way if one starts with a finite string such as $1,2,3,4,5$.  Leibniz understood the term in the same sense.  The famous paradox described already by Galileo points out that the correspondence $n \mapsto n^2$ gives a  1-1 correspondence between $\mathbb N$ and its proper subset. Based on his understanding of Galileo's paradox, Leibniz...

Comment: ... similarly rejected the actual infinity represented by $\mathbb N$ and other infinite entities such as the unending line.  @MoziburUllah